# Is there a way to give meaningful names for Tuple items?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Retrieving items from a `Tuple` is done by accessing the `ItemX` property.
Is there a way of naming each item so that using the Tuple will be more readable?

**Code:**

Looking for something like this:

```
Dim l As New Tuple(Of String, Integer)
l.Name
l.ID
```

Instead of:

```
Dim l As New Tuple(Of String, Integer)
l.Item1
l.Item2
```

Comment: Yes, in more recent releases of VB.Net. The syntax is here:
[stackoverflow.com/questions/54942526](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54942526/is-possible-to-create-a-generic-list-of-named-tuples-in-visual-basic)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's nothing in the tuple type that helps you out here. Options:

- If you need to pass the values in multiple methods, create your own type with appropriate properties. (You *could* derive from `Tuple` here if you really want, and just provide properties which delegate to `Item1` and `Item2`, but I'm not sure I would)
- If you only need the values within one method, use an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

In C# 7 Version we have the feature to give friendly name to Tuple Values. 
Note: Just directly typed the code here not compiled.

e.g

```
(int Latitude, int Longitude, string city) GetPlace()
{
    return(20,30,"New York");    
}

var geoLocation = GetPlace();
WriteLine($"Latitude :{geoLocation.Latitude}, Longitude:{geoLocation.Longitude}, City:{geoLocation.city}");
```

Comment: Note to potential future readers: This answer was posted before C# 7 was released. So the exact syntax is still subject to change. (Personally, I would have waited before posting this)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a couple of extension methods for Tuple: First that returns the first element, and Rest that returns a subtuple from the second element onward. That might be both a generic *and* easy-on-the-eyes solution.

If you call First car and Rest cdr, you're going to make a lot of people very happy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR .