# Is possible to create a generic list of named tuples in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

In C# (7+) I can declare ([Better naming in Tuple classes than "Item1", "Item2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745938/better-naming-in-tuple-classes-than-item1-item2))

```
var myList = new List<(int first, int second)>();
```

and later on refer to items:

```
var a = myList[0].second;
```

Is there an equivalent syntax in VB.NET?

**Edit**
From Andrew Morton's answer, the equivalent syntax is:

```vb
Dim myList = New List(Of (first As Integer, second As Integer))
Dim a = myList(0).second
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, see [Tuples (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples).

```
Dim q As New List(Of (EventDate As Date, Name As String, IsHoliday As Boolean))
q.Add((EventDate:=#2019-01-01#, Name:="New Year's Day", IsHoliday:=True))
q.Add((New DateTime(2019, 6, 21), "Summer solstice", False))

Console.WriteLine(q(0).Name) ''outputs "New Year's Day"
Console.WriteLine(q(1).IsHoliday) ''outputs False
```

(Visual Studio 2017 and later.)